# How make image view to float like bubble on screen?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to make an android application in which i would like to have bubbles which float on the screen when some action takes place. Could some one please help me here. I am breaking my head for the past four days but i could not make it up. So please help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mention the language you are developing on..

Comment: Sorry i have edited my question and i am developing in android.

Comment: @Prabhu have you done the above task. if yes can u please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ImageViews, for your use case, it would be better to use a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to handle the drawing yourself.

Draw a canvas fullscreen with a transparent background. Create an array of bitmaps(one for each image you want to draw, remember to use a circle mask to make them bubble shaped, watch out for memory issues) and draw them to screen at different positions.

Use a custom RNG algorithm to generate appropriate positions for your bitmaps, and then draw them on the canvas. Use a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) to handle the animations.

[Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg30548.html)'s the code for generating a circular cropped bitmap:

```
int targetWidth = 100;
    int targetHeight = 100;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        targetWidth,
        targetHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(
        ((float)targetWidth - 1) / 2,
        ((float)targetHeight - 1) / 2,
        (Math.min(((float)targetWidth), ((float)targetHeight)) / 2),
        Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        getResources(),
        R.drawable.my_image);
    canvas.drawBitmap(
        sourceBitmap,
        new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
        new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight),
        null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
```

Of course, you will have to modify this code to draw the bitmap to the canvas instead of setting it in the ImageView. It would be more efficient, to crop the Bitmap once, then place the cropped image into the array of Bitmaps.

Comment: Yes i tried this. it is just drawing a image view through canvas. Could you please explain a bit more how to animate like floating bubble. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, build an RNG generator that'll generate positions for your bubbles that will make them vary in X(either left or right) and Y(only upwards)

Comment: No, I can't. Sorry if I'm being rude, but SO isn't a place to ask others to do things for you. Researching google and applying your mind is more than enough to implement something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Change the imageview position at run time using this code

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
        layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, righ, bottom);
        yourImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i use the above code snippet it is just relocating the position of the image view. how could i set animation like float like bubble.

Comment: you can do this in a thread of in a loop what ever you want. and increase the variable at every tick, then you imageview looks floating

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality only using live wallpaper in android.
I have created many floating objects live papers in Andengine! :) 
so you can ask me further if you have any confusion

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. my doubts is can we able to make the same animation in application.